How to correctly index into an index buffer in DXR
I am working through a simple ray-tracing application with DXR. I am using a single vertex and index buffer for multiple geometries, and the acceleration structure is handling that perfectly.  Everything is working fine, and I can get simple 'shadow' rays casting after a primary ray is cast to create some really basic shadows. For the next step, I've attempted to get access to the normals in my vertex buffer, but I am really at a loss on how to actually index into the vertices in the closest hit shader.
My relevant shader bindings are:

acceleration structure at t0
index buffer at t1
vertex buffer at t2
instance buffer at t3

The three buffers are all StructuredBuffers.
I have tried:

Using InstanceID(), e.g. index = index_b[InstanceID()], which of course doesn't work, as this is the index into the instance buffer.
Using PrimitiveIndex(), which the specs say is the triangle index. This gives data, but it's so wrong I have no idea really where it is accessing into the index buffer.
Passing the index offset of the mesh along through the instance buffer, e.g. index = index_b[PrimitiveIndex() + inst.index_offset]
Multiplying PrimitiveIndex() by 3, and using this as the base index into the index buffer. This is closest to correct, as it actually gives data from the index buffer, but the normals are all incorrect when indexing.

None of these work, and I'm sure it's because I am woefully misunderstanding the various auto-generated ids. I'm sure that I need some sort of combination of: what index offset this mesh starts at, what triangle I am in in this mesh, and two extra indices in order to interpolate a normal with the barcentrics.
Also, perhaps it is not smart to use a single vertex and index buffer with DXR? If not, I'm really not sure how to go about binding different vbs and ibs to access in the ray tracing shaders.
I've tried using RenderDoc to see what my buffers look like, but sadly DXR is not supported. I've also tried NVIDIANsight, but I can't actually seem to see what the data contained in the bound buffers is, like you can in RenderDoc.

Sure enough, I figured it out a little after posting.
The solution to this is found in combining my attempts 3 and 4. Consider the following index buffer:
uint indices[] = {
    0,1,2,               ---> mesh 0, triangle 0
    
    3,4,5,               ---> mesh 1, triangle 0
    5,6,3,                            triangle 1

    7,8,9,               ---> mesh 2, triangle 0
    9,10,7,                           triangle 1
    11,12,13,                         triangle 2
    13,14,11,                         triangle 3

    etc.
}

By means of PrimitiveIndex(), we can move between triangles. If we can also send the index offset of a mesh in the buffer with the instances. Then, a given triangle's indices are:
base_index = PrimitiveIndex() * 3 + instance.index_offset
index0 = base_index + 0
index1 = base_index + 1
index2 = base_index + 2

Finally, make sure your vertex buffers are appropriately padded so that they are aligned on 8 byte lanes. (This is actually what was ultimately killing the offsets.)
